# vba excel: PasteSpecial for JPEG not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that has been working, and all of the sudden it is not. I have tried everything and cannot figure out why. It works when I do a step by step (F8) but not when I run the code. What the code is doing is finding an ID in column B, and finding the jpg that has the same image (in the file H:\Images...) and pasting it into the 1st column. The code produces the error "Run-time error 1004: PasteSpecial method of worksheet class failed" and highlights the ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial line. Please help!

```
Sub Picture()
 Dim picname As String

Dim lThisRow As Long

lThisRow = 3

Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")

    Cells(lThisRow, 1).Select 'This is where picture will be inserted


     picname = Cells(lThisRow, 2) 'This is the picture name
    'MsgBox (picname)

    Dim DirFile As String
    DirFile = "H:\Images\9 Thumbnails\" & picname & ".jpg"
    If Len(Dir(DirFile)) = 0 Then
      'MsgBox "File does not exist"

    Else
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("H:\Images\9 Thumbnails\" & picname & ".jpg").Select
        Selection.Cut

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False

     'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(DirFile)
             With Selection
                .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.9, msoTrue
                .Left = Cells(lThisRow, 1).Left + Cells(lThisRow, 1).Width / 2 - Selection.ShapeRange.Width / 2
                .Top = Cells(lThisRow, 1).Top + Cells(lThisRow, 1).Height / 2 - Selection.ShapeRange.Height / 2

                '.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

                ''.ShapeRange.Width = 80#
                .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
            End With
    End If

lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
Loop

Range("B3").Select
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to guess some of your issue will be your use of `.Select`.  It's best practice to [Avoid Using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  When stepping through it, it's a line by line process, so VBA is less likely to confuse worksheets/selections.  When running as a macro, as fast as it can, this can likely cause issues.

Comment: ilm gessing (jpeg) is not available as pasting, and anyway this is what I am using ; `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)"`

Comment: on further advice, if you want to avoid using select after the pastespecial, you can use this : `Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)` , (pic is declared as shape)

Comment: Thank you both for your help, the metafile option did not work. Since I am not that experienced at writing code, I am not sure how to try the other two (not using .select or setting the pic as a shape). I am going to start trying now. But if will probably take me hours so if you have any hints on how to go about it, they would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer using .addpicture. This changes the way you have to look at dimensions, but I figured that out too. Final code:

```
Sub Picture()
 Dim picname As String
 Dim PicPath As String
 Dim lThisRow As Long
 Dim Pic As Shape
 Dim rngPic As Range


lThisRow = 3

Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")

    Set rngPic = Cells(lThisRow, 1) 'This is where picture will be inserted

    picname = Cells(lThisRow, 2) 'This is the picture name

    present = Dir("H:\Images\8 Thumbnails\" & picname & ".jpg")
    PicPath = ("H:\Images\8 Thumbnails\" & picname & ".jpg")

    If present <> "" Then

      Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)

      With Pic
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        If .Height < 45 Then .Height = 115
        If .Width > 150 Then .Width = 150
        .Left = rngPic.Left + rngPic.Width / 2 - Pic.Width / 2
        .Top = rngPic.Top + rngPic.Height / 2 - Pic.Height / 2
      End With

    Else

    Cells(lThisRow, 1) = ""

    End If

lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
Loop

Range("B3").Select
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```